# Translator software

Tags: translation

Is there a software  that can translate to your preferred language in while using another software i.e you download a file only to find some text is in Russian.
Which software can I get to the text translated to English?

Comment: What did you try sofar? Did you have a look at Google Translate and when it is not appropriate state why, also state your Operating System and your budget restrictions and other relevant information.

Comment: Haven't tried any. I thought Google translate translatez websites. I downloaded a game and wanted to add a text in a certain file but I found it was in Chinese. So locating where to place my text is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

As no better answers have been put forward I'll suggest good old Google translate, if non copyable text is what you need to translate, Google translate can translate from pictures so you could screenshot the text or program. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I thought Google translate works on websites.   I need to add some text in a file from a game I downloaded but the text is in Chinese

Answer (score 1):

You can try [MacLinguist](http://maclinguist.com), it basically does what you asked: you select a chunk of text in any application, double-press Control and have the translation pop up (you can also replace currently selected text with the translation if you press Alt, while holding Control). It works for both **Mac** and **Windows**:
[image]